# how to add uuid in logger better way

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, logging, uuid

```
------------program1.ts
    consumerGroup.on('message',function(msgc){
                
             uuid=uuid();       
             program2.func2(uuid,msgc);
    
    });
    
    ------Program2.ts
    function func2(uuid,msgc){
    logger.log(uuid,msgc);
         program3.func3(uuid,msgc);
    }
    
    -----------program3.ts
    function func(uuid,msgc){
         logger.log(uuid,msgc);
    }
```

I have to implement UUID in the logger for each message read from the consumer in an existing project. I came up similar to the above code approach but there are lots of sub-functions and I would have to do it for each and every function/logger call.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Node 14 and above, you can use the built-in [AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_class_asynclocalstorage).  Logging with IDs is a typical use-case of this new API. Here's an example of the use-case:

```js
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');
const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

function logWithId(msg) {
  const id = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
  logger.log(id, msg);
}

asyncLocalStorage.run(uuid(), () => {
  consumerGroup.on('message',function(msgc){
     program2.func2(msgc);
  });
})

// ------Program2.ts
function func2(uuid,msgc){
  logWithId(msgc);
  program3.func3(msgc);
}
    
// -----------program3.ts
function func(uuid,msgc){
  logWithId(msgc);
}
```

Read the docs to understand more about it.

Comment: @HimNG, did this answer your question?